# Define static methods from list programmatically

Tags: python, static-methods

I have an object with a base method `log(text, level)`, a list of `levels`, and I define, by hand, each method like this:

```
@staticmethod
def <level>(text):
     log.log(text, '<level>')
```

(Where `<level>` is to be replaced with one of the list's items)
How could I do it programmatically?

Also, my `levels` list is actually a dict, and the `<level>` is the key, but I know how to iterate over that.

Comment: A) the `logging` module has exactly that and b) the methods are defined manually there for good reasons (see PEP-20).

Comment: also look into python attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setattr` function like this for every level, notice use of `staticmethod` wrapper function.

```
for level in LOG_TYPES:
    setattr(A, level, staticmethod(lambda text, level=level: log.log(text, level)))
```

EDIT:
You have to add `level=level` in lambda declaration, otherwise all lambdas refer to the same `level`, which happens to be the last one assigned.

Comment: Tried it, everything worked except for the `'<level>'` inside the function definition. How can I access it outside of the function definition?

Comment: I tried this: `for level in LOG_TYPES:
    setattr(log, level, staticmethod(lambda text: log.log(text, level)))`

And it always uses the last element of my `LOG_TYPES` list, regardless of the function defined :/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate code then use something like [mako](https://www.makotemplates.org/) or [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). You want to keep the generation of you code and the actual code that your program runs separate. This is mainly because code generated in python is much more frustrating to debug.

For instance, in Python you could generate your code like this:

```
from textwrap import dedent

class Logger:
    for level in ('debug', 'info'):
        exec(dedent("""
            @staticmethod
            def {level}(text):
                log.log(text, {level!r})
        """.format(level=level)))

Logger.info('test')
```

But then on an exception your stack trace will be confusing eg.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\a.py", line 18, in <module>
    Logger.info('test')
  File "<string>", line 4, in info <-- what is <string> and where can you find it?
NameError: name 'log' is not defined
```

Instead you could try:

```
class Logger:
    def gen_log_func(level):
        def _log(text):
            log.log(text, level)
        _log.__name__ = level
        return _log

    for level in ('debug', 'info'):
        locals()[level] = staticmethod(gen_log_func(level))

    del gen_log_func

Logger.info('test')
```

Better, but this sill looks pretty messy. Further linters still can't help you with typos in function and attribute names. For all the linter knows, `Logger.info` is just as much a typo as `Logger.inf`.

With mako, you could write a template file like this:

```
<%
    levels = 'debug', 'info'
%>
class Logger:
    % for level in levels:
    @staticmethod
    def ${level}(text):
        log.log(text, ${repr(level)})

    % endfor
```

Here the ugliness of the template is captured inside a template file, and the generated code just looks like normal, fully-expressed code.